# Linux GLEW with GLX segfault (core dumped)

Tags: linux, opengl, glew, glx

I am trying to set up in Linux a very basic program with OpenGL 3.2 core profile, and GLEW. I tried that with the help of this [article](http://renderingpipeline.com/2012/05/windowless-opengl/).

This is my code:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>

//#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "stb_image_write.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <GL/glfw.h>


static float _viewPortHeight = 30;
static float _viewPortWidth = 10;

typedef GLXContext (*glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)(Display*, GLXFBConfig, GLXContext, Bool, const int*);
typedef Bool (*glXMakeContextCurrentARBProc)(Display*, GLXDrawable, GLXDrawable, GLXContext);
static glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc glXCreateContextAttribsARB = NULL;
static glXMakeContextCurrentARBProc   glXMakeContextCurrentARB   = NULL;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    glXCreateContextAttribsARB = (glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc) glXGetProcAddressARB( (const GLubyte *) "glXCreateContextAttribsARB" );
    glXMakeContextCurrentARB   = (glXMakeContextCurrentARBProc)   glXGetProcAddressARB( (const GLubyte *) "glXMakeContextCurrent");
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (display == NULL){
        std::cout  << "error getting the X display";
        return -1;
     }

    static int visualAttribs[] = {None};
    int numberOfFrameBufferConfigurations;
    GLXFBConfig *fbConfigs = glXChooseFBConfig(display, DefaultScreen(display), visualAttribs, &numberOfFrameBufferConfigurations);

     int context_attribs[] = {
          GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB ,3,
          GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2,
          GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, GLX_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB,
          GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, GLX_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,None
     };

    std::cout << "initialising context...";
    GLXContext openGLContext = glXCreateContextAttribsARB(display, fbConfigs[0], 0, True, context_attribs);

    int pBufferAttribs[] = {
        GLX_PBUFFER_WIDTH, 32,
        GLX_PBUFFER_HEIGHT, 32,
        None
    };

    GLXPbuffer pbuffer = glXCreatePbuffer(display, fbConfigs[0], pBufferAttribs);
    XFree(fbConfigs);
    XSync(display, False);
    if(!glXMakeContextCurrent(display, pbuffer, pbuffer, openGLContext)){
        std::cout << "error with content creation";
        return -1;
    }
    glXMakeCurrent(display, pbuffer, openGLContext);

    GLenum error = glewInit();
    if (error != GLEW_OK){
       std::cout << "error with glew init()\n";
    }else{
        std::cout << "glew is ok\n\n";
    }
    GLuint test;
    GLuint framebuffer;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);

    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    std::string path("output.png");
    exportToPath(path);

    return 0;
 }
```

The output I get is this:

> Initialising context... glew is ok
>
> Segmentation Fault (core dumped)

The line that is causing the problem is at the `glGenFrameBuffers` call, which is also the first call to the functions produced by GLEW. Something is very wrong here, but I can't seem to figure out what and why.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where is the declaration of `framebuffer` ?

Comment: You are right. Sorry about that. I edited the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, whose solution seems to be the addition of 'glewExperimental' = GL_TRUE before the call to glewInit();

Answer (score 1):

`glew.h` already includes `gl.h` and with GLX available `glx.h`… and then uses some macro magic to bend some symbols. I suggest you remove the lines

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>
```

And just use

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

With the original includes in place after the GLEW include some of the macro magic might get lost and you end up with a wrongly associated symbol resulting in the crash.

---

On a side note: Why do you include GLFW and GLUT headers? If your intention is to use naked GLX then you don't need them and should not include them.